# Types loaded from an assembly file are not equal to the same type when referenced in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I take a `Type`, query its assembly location, and then load the assembly from the same address, and find the same type from the loaded assembly. The resulting type is not equal to the original type.

Here's the test case:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTypeLoadingWithFilePath()
{
    var originalType = typeof(SomeClass);
    var assemblyAddress = originalType.Assembly.Location;

    var loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyAddress);
    Assert.IsNotNull(loadedAssembly);

    var loadedType = loadedAssembly.GetType(originalType.FullName);
    Assert.IsNotNull(loadedType);

    Assert.AreEqual(originalType, loadedType);
}
```

The test fails on the last assertion.

This only happens on .NET Core on Windows. (I'm testing against latest version, 2.1.4). But this was not the case with .NET Framework.

My questions are:

- Is this by design, or a bug?
- If it's by design, why?
- Again, if it's by design, doesn't this mean different behavior between two implementations of .NET Standard? (.NET Core vs. .NET Framework)

Comment: what happen if testing against UnderlyingSystemType? I mean: Assert.AreEqual(originalType, loadedType.UnderlyingSystemType); Does the test pass?

Comment: Nope. Fails with `UnderlyingSystemType` too.

Comment: I also reported this to CoreFX team on GitHub for direct feedback. For reference: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27004

Comment: Thaks, I will monitor the issue, it is very weird...

Comment: Just fyi the assembly of the original type is not the same assembly as the one you have loaded.. not that it really helps...but you know more info

Comment: @Dave could you elaborate? Didn't get your point.

Comment: It was just something to note, that if you compare the loaded assembly with originalType.Assembly they are not equal (in the .Net Core version). So its not to do with the types not being the same, its because the Assembly the types are from are different

Answer (score 7):

This is a normal behavior. Using `Assembly.LoadFile` will load the assembly and create a new "instance" of it. To fix this, simply use `Assembly.LoadFrom` instead. This will first look in the current context if the requested assembly is already loaded, and take this one if it is. Comparing types like you're doing will then work.

Edit: I don't know if it's intended, but this method works in both .NetFramework and .NetCore.

Comment: I confirm that `LoadFrom` worked as intended. But the change in the behavior of a previous method, or difference between netframework and netcore, is weird and makes me think it should be a bug or something.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of netframework using the GAC (no GAC for netcore).