# Implementations of .NET Standard behave differently

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

While loading assemblies, two implementations of Dot Net Standard behave differently.
I've tested the following code as a console application in both **DotNetCore 2.0** (`dotnet --version` is `2.1.4`) and **DotNetFramework 4.6.1**

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var referencedType = typeof(SampleType);
    var referenceTypeAssembly = referencedType.Assembly;

    var manuallyLoadedAssembly_Method_Load = Assembly.Load(referenceTypeAssembly.GetName());
    var resolvedType_Method_Load =
        manuallyLoadedAssembly_Method_Load.GetType(referencedType.FullName);


    var manuallyLoadedAssembly_Method_LoadFile = Assembly.LoadFile(referenceTypeAssembly.Location);
    var resolvedType_Method_LoadFile = manuallyLoadedAssembly_Method_LoadFile.GetType(referencedType.FullName);

    var manuallyLoadedAssembly_Method_LoadFrom = Assembly.LoadFrom(referenceTypeAssembly.Location);
    var resolvedType_Method_LoadFrom = manuallyLoadedAssembly_Method_LoadFrom.GetType(referencedType.FullName);

    Console.WriteLine(
        $"are equal {nameof(referencedType)}=={nameof(resolvedType_Method_Load)}:" +
        $"{referencedType == resolvedType_Method_Load}");

    Console.WriteLine(
        $"are equal {nameof(referencedType)}=={nameof(resolvedType_Method_LoadFile)}:" +
        $"{referencedType == resolvedType_Method_LoadFile}");

    Console.WriteLine(
        $"are equal {nameof(referencedType)}=={nameof(resolvedType_Method_LoadFrom)}:" +
        $"{referencedType == resolvedType_Method_LoadFrom}");
}
```

The results:

**In DotNetCore 2.0**

```
are equal referencedType==resolvedType_Method_Load:True
are equal referencedType==resolvedType_Method_LoadFile:False
are equal referencedType==resolvedType_Method_LoadFrom:True
```

**In DotNetFramework 4.6.1**

```
are equal referencedType==resolvedType_Method_Load:True
are equal referencedType==resolvedType_Method_LoadFile:True
are equal referencedType==resolvedType_Method_LoadFrom:True
```

As these two both implement Dot Net Standard, I am a little confused about the fact that they do different things running the same code.

After a little investigation and reading up I ended up finding there are actually two totally different implementations behind the two versions.

Is there an explanation of **why** there is inconsistency in running the same code on different implementations of DotNet Standard?

Or a better question might be:

*Does Dot Net Standard guarantee consistency in behavior between different flavors of its implementation or merely the **Interface** that programmers code against?*

For further investigation and references one might want to look at the following:

[Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,543e1b0d5fb43a97) you can see the **DotNetFramework** implementation of `Assembly.LoadFile`.

Here you can see the **DotNetCore** implementation of the same method.

```
public static Assembly LoadFile(string path)
{
  AppDomain.CheckLoadFileSupported();
  Assembly assembly = (Assembly) null;
  if (path == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof (path));
  if (PathInternal.IsPartiallyQualified(path))
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.Argument_AbsolutePathRequired, nameof (path));
  string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
  lock (Assembly.s_loadfile)
  {
    if (Assembly.s_loadfile.TryGetValue(fullPath, out assembly))
      return assembly;
    assembly = new IndividualAssemblyLoadContext().LoadFromAssemblyPath(fullPath);
    Assembly.s_loadfile.Add(fullPath, assembly);
  }
  return assembly;
}
```

Comment: .NET Framework and .NET Core are totalyl different target Frameworks. They are as dissimilar as .NET and Mono. This was propably a change they wanted to make (like Dropping WindowsForms) but could only do with the swap to .NET Core.

Comment: The quick answer to "Does Dot Net Standard guarantee consistency in behavior between different flavors of its implementation?" is "no." Especially in areas such as this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Types loaded from an assembly file are not equal to the same type when referenced in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48711862).